# how to run this procedure as a normal user

Tags: sql, oracle

i have create procedure like this,THIS IS WORK AS `SYS` AND `SYSDBA` ,BUT I WANT TO RUN THIS MY newly created USER ACCOUNT `DEMOUSER` PLEASE HELP ME....

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE E_Types as
   PROCEDURE TestProc (p_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR);
END E_Types;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY E_Types IS
    PROCEDURE TestProc (p_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
    BEGIN
        OPEN p_recordset
         FOR select a.TABLESPACE_NAME                                   Tablespace
                  , round((1-((a.BYTES-nvl(b.BYTES,0))/a.BYTES))*100,2) Percentages 
               from (
                       select TABLESPACE_NAME
                            , sum(BYTES) BYTES
                         from sys.dba_data_files
                     group by TABLESPACE_NAME
                    ) a
                  , (
                       select TABLESPACE_NAME
                            , sum(BYTES) BYTES
                         from sys.dba_free_space
                     group by TABLESPACE_NAME
                    ) b where a.TABLESPACE_NAME = b.TABLESPACE_NAME (+)
           order by ((a.BYTES-b.BYTES)/a.BYTES) desc
                  ;
     END;
END;
/
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? If so, *what does it say*?

Comment: Where is your package being created? In DEMOUSER or in other schema? If it is not in DEMOUSER then execute privilege has to be granted to DEMOUSER in order execute.

Comment: Never ever create procedures (or *any* database object) as the SYS (or SYSTEM account). Stop using those special accounts for your development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to grant SELECT privileges on the used objects to your user (as SYS):

```
GRANT SELECT ON dba_free_space TO demouser;
GRANT SELECT ON dba_data_files TO demouser;
```

Afterwards, you can create your procedure in the DEMOUSER schema.

And, BTW: You should **never** create or change objects in the SYS schema. AFAIK, this will void any chance of getting support from Oracle.

Comment: thanx Damien ,Polppan, and thanx for the advice a house with no name i'm new to oracle and pl/sql and i am trying to measure oracle database performane (tablespace usage,precess,lock like things...)